# Stored Procedure In Oracle 11g database

Tags: stored-procedures, oracle11g

I want to do insert,update,delete and select statement in one stored procedure 
using oracle 11 g database.If any one know this ,please help me to do this.

Answer (score -1):

STORED PROCEDURE EXAMPLE for AGENT

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE GET_AGENT
     (V_CUR IN OUT SYS_REFCURSOR)
    AS
    BEGIN
      OPEN V_CUR FOR SELECT * FROM AGENT;
    END GET_EMPLOYEES;



INSERT INTO AGENT VALUES(:AGENTID,:AGENTNAME)



DELETE FROM AGENT WHERE AGENTID=:AGENTID



UPDATE AGENT SET AGENTNAME=:AGENTNAME WHERE AGENTID=:AGENTID




UPDATE AGENT SET AGENTNAME=:AGENTNAME,..... WHERE ROWID=:RECORD_ROWID
DELETE FROM AGENT WHERE ROWID=:RECORD_ROWID
```